# Python 'Property' behave strangely

Tags: python, properties

Look at the code below.

```
class CCC:
    @property
    def n(self):
        print('getter called')
        return self.__dict__['n']

    @n.setter
    def n(self, value):
        print('setter called')
        self.__dict__['n'] = value


c = CCC()
c.n = 5
print(CCC.__dict__)
print(c.__dict__)
print(c.n)
```

It is the result of execution

```
setter called
{'__module__': '__main__', 'n': <property object at 0x000000000289CC28>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'CCC' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'CCC' objects>, '__doc__': None}
{'n': 5}
getter called # I do not understand why this sentence is printed. 
5
```

I do not understand why 'getter' was printed. `CCC` has an `n` property object. `c` has an `n` as integer. when I print `c.n`, must print just `c.\__dict__['n']`. Instead, 'getter called' was printed. What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't be messing with stuff like `__dict__` (or anything with a surrounded by `__`) unless you really know what you're doing and really need it.

That said, you create a property with a getter (implicit) and a setter (explicit). The getter returns the value `self.__dict__['n']` while the setter assigns a value there.

Later on, you create an instance of `CCC` and use the setter in `c.n = 5`. Then you're printing the `__dict__` of the `CCC` class which is telling you there is a property called `n`. Afterwards, you see the `__dict__` of your instance `c` which due to the setting holds the value `5`.

So, since you're accessing the `n` property when doing `c.n`. When you're doing `self.__dict__['n']` you're also getting the value stored there, which you did define, via the setter, as `5`.

And since you wrote a `print` function in your getter, then that's what you get printed.

Perhaps doing by calling the key in the `__dict__` in the setter/getter would help you declutter your thought

```
class CCC:
    @property
    def n(self):
        print('getter called')
        return self.__dict__['nval']

    @n.setter
    def n(self, value):
        print('setter called')
        self.__dict__['nval'] = value


c = CCC()
c.n = 5
print(CCC.__dict__)
print(c.__dict__)
print(c.n)
```

Now we don't have a mental name collision between the property `n` and the key in `__dict__`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i'm wandering i assigned 'n' as integer on instance c it is same name as CCC.n. when i access c.n, search at instance c.n first i guess, not CCC.n. i know it was wrong. but i dont know why.

Comment: @SuziHan sorry, did not understand the comment.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what's going on underneath?